# $5\times 5$ Matrix $A$ such that $A^5 = I_5$ (in $R^5$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm stuck on an exercise I got in my linear algebra class where you have to find a $5\times5$ matrix $A$ such that $A$ multiplied by itself five times is the identity matrix $I_5.$ $A$ must not be the identity matrix itself.

My problem is that I don't know how to go about this in a clever way. I know that it makes sense to put only ones on the main diagonal of A and only zeroes below the ones but I don't know how to construct the rest of the matrix. It seems tedious to just try out random examples and I want to do it systematically.
Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: In which field are you working?

Comment: Take the permutation matrix of a 5-cycle in $\mathfrak{S}_5$. *E.g.* the matrix for $\sigma=(n,1,2,3,...,n-1)$ is a sup-diagonal of ones and a single one last line first column.

Comment: Follow up : Does anyone knows if any two such matrices commute ?

Comment: @P.Quinton Not necessarily. My example still works : different permutations commute iff they have disjoint supports. Take two *distinct* 5-cycles, their matrix won't commute.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot.

Comment: (More generally, if you have a conjugation-invariant condition, you wouldn't usually expect the set of matrices satisfying it to be commutative.  Of course this isn't a theorem—the condition "equals the identity" violates this expectation—but it is a reasonable heuristic.)

Comment: Thank you! @AnthonySaint-Criq 
Unfortunately, I only just started studying at university last year and we didn't cover permutations in depth, but I will look into what you suggested.

Comment: Take a matrix that rotates by $2\pi/5$ radians in two dimensions and that leave the other three dimensions fixed.

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq has given an excellent [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3984008/5-times-5-matrix-a-such-that-a5-i-5#comment8220689_3984008), but, especially if it's not clear to you in retrospect why it was a good example, you might try with just the $2\times2$ case.  This will help you avoid thinking of matrices as "the diagonal and some other stuff", as is too easy to do in elementary linear algebra.

Comment: @Mankind, I think that [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3984008/5-times-5-matrix-a-such-that-a5-i-5#comment8220713_3984008) is why @‍mathcounterexamples.net asked about the ground field (or even ring?).  If you want a matrix over $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Q$, for example, this rotation isn't good; or, for example, if you're working over $\mathbb C$, then you might as well just take various 5th roots of unity on the diagonal!

Comment: Right, I'm sorry I forgot to mention that it's a matrix over the real numbers!

Comment: @SokraTess, a permutation matrix is one obtained by permuting the rows of the identity matrix.  To save you time: see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationMatrix.html.  Look at the rightmost matrix in (1) and multiply it by itself.  Also, examine its effect when multiplying it into the vector $[x_1, x_2]^{T}$.  Now go through a similar exercise with 3-by-3 permutation matrices.

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq : You wrote "different permutations commute iff they have disjoint supports." But the first and second powers of a five-cycle commute with each other.

Comment: @MichaelHardy you are correct, sorry !

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward example would be a matrix that [rotates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) on two of the dimensions by some multiple of $72^\circ$ - as noted in comments here by @BenGrossmann this is a [Givens rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation).

---

... and I now noticed Anthony Saint-Criq's permutation suggestion & subsequent discussion in main comments, that's even easier (as well as being numerically stable), e.g.
$\tiny\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ - ensuring you get a 5-cycle as described (not eg 3+2 length cycles, although that would be a neat way to have $A^{\color{violet}{6}}=I_5$ ).

Comment: Also answered by @Mankind in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3984008/5-times-5-matrix-a-such-that-a5-i-5-in-r5#comment8220713_3984008).

Comment: I think that the idea of rotating "on two of the dimensions" should be clarified. In particular, it is worth noting that the kind of matrix that you have in mind is (I suspect) a [Givens rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation).

Comment: @LSpice if it's worth talking about notes in main comments, it's worth checking the time stamps and seeing that the main comments reference to rotation was only just before my answer and not highlighted at the time.

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, hence my original link to the rotation matrix page. Thanks for the extra terminology on this form of matrix.

Comment: Joffan, the permutation matrix is also the companion matrix for $x^5-1$ so little imagination is needed

Comment: @WillJagy thanks for another way of viewing this.

Answer (score 2):

the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) for polynomial $x^5 - 1$  is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&1 \\
1&0&0&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
or, if preferred, the transpose of this.